# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable - when customizing loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, autograd

When I am customizing the loss function in Keras, it seems that the gradient cannot be tracked (or not computed?). I am doing an unsupervised learning problem, so only the y_pred is useful.

This is my temporary code below. Before, I tried `assign` to save the result of `log_prob`, however, I have seen that there is [there is no gradient computed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6193). Therefore, I use a list -> variable instead.

```
def custom_loss(mu_est):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, [n,d])
        n_samples, _ = y_pred.shape
        kk, _ = mu_est.shape
        log_prob = []
        for k, mu in enumerate(mu_est):
            mu = mu.astype(np.float32)
            y = y_pred - mu
            log_prob.append(K.sum(K.square(y), axis=1))
        log_prob = K.variable(log_prob)
        log_prob = K.transpose(log_prob)
        log_prob = K.cast(log_prob, tf.float64)
        weighted_log_prob = K.log(pi_k_est) - 0.5 * (d * K.log(2*np.pi*sigma2) + log_prob/sigma2)
        temp = K.logsumexp(weighted_log_prob, axis=1)
        return - K.sum(temp) / n_samples
    return loss
```

Comment: K.cast is not differentiable, and also why are you using K.variable there?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have replaced K.cast by setting `K.set_floatx('float64')` first, but it still goes wrong. Using `K.variable` is because I want to save the computed result (like np.array), then it can be processed by `K.logsumexp`.

Comment: No, you should not use K.variable, that is not how it is used, and by  doing that, you are breaking the gradient chain and getting this error.